# Can't resolve 'fs' after installing mapbox-gl-draw-circle

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

I'm using this npm library in my react ts project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl-draw-circle.

Because it doesn't support ts I needed to create a declaration file (which I did).
But because it uses 'require('./lib/modes/CircleMode') etc. in it self I get a
"Error in ./node_moudles/jsonlint-lines/lib/jsonlint.js 942:17-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '....../node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib'"
I have no access to the webpack config file because I created the app using 'create react app' and I wish to leave it untouched and not to extract and start managing it.
I also added to the package.json file "browser": { "fs": false, "path": false", "os": false" } but this isn't helpfull

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Create React App do you use?

Comment: I'm using React V17.0.2 and ts V4.6.3 how can I check the 'create-react-app' version I used?

Comment: The 'react-scripts' version is 5.0.0

Comment: I'm not sure `browser` key in `package.json` changes anything in webpack config, do you have proof that it should work?

Comment: Also did you check out [issues of this package's repository](https://github.com/iamanvesh/mapbox-gl-draw-circle/issues), as they are describing similiar errors?

Comment: The browser key in package.json doesn't change anything. all the other solutions I found required extracting the webpack and reconfiguring it...

Comment: Have you considered using CRACO, which allows some extent of webpack configuration without ejecting?